# Compare a string to elements of list in a foreach loop c#

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I deserialized an xml file in order to perform some treatment and write results in  an other xml file,

Deserialization :

```
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Network));
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"path\XmlFile.xml");
        object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        Network XmlData = (Network)obj;
        reader.Close();
```

I got "ROUTES" elements of my xml in a list

[Some content of the "ROUTES" list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Z5k.png)

Now I want to browse this list to compare a string that is given on the command line (OriginSignal) to the value of the child element "ENTRANCESIGNAL" of each "ROUTE" element of the list

I tried this :

```
        string OriginSignal = null;
        Console.WriteLine("");
        OriginSignal = Console.ReadLine();
        foreach (var route in XmlData.ROUTES)
        {
            if (OriginSignal.Equals(XmlData.ROUTES[].ENTRANCESIGNAL))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(XmlData.ROUTES[].ID);     
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I don't know what to put in ROUTES[] as index.

I tried with `XmlData.ROUTES[route]` but I'm getting an error `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'XmlData.ROUTES' to 'int'`

I'm a beginner in c# programming, so I would like to have some help to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `foreach` loop here. `foreach` doesn't use an index, instead it returns an element in the collection during each iteration. In this case, `route` variable contains an element in the collection during each iteration. You need to compare the element with `OriginalSignal`.

```
   foreach (var route in XmlData.ROUTES)
   { 
    if(OriginalSignal.Equals(route.ENTRANCESIGNAL))
    {
    Console.WriteLine(route.ID);  
    }
   }
```

Follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) to learn more on foreach loops.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an index for your array as you're using a foreach loop, which instantiates your `route` variable with the next element in the array for each iteration of the loop. You just need to use your variable:

```
foreach (var route in XmlData.ROUTES)
{
    if (OriginSignal.Equals(route.ENTRANCESIGNAL));
    {
        Console.WriteLine(route.ID);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it if I understood the question correctly.
You don't have to use an index. A foreach basically loops through all of the elements in the XmlData.ROUTES and the var route is always the current item.

```
  foreach (var route in XmlData.ROUTES)
    {
        if (String.Equals(OriginSignal, route.ENTRANCESIGNAL)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(route.ID);     
        }
    }
```